# SQLGetPrivateProfileString failed with

Tags: command-line, odbc, dsn, rhel6

Typing the command: odbcinst -q -s on RHEL 6, I get the following error message:

```
odbcinst: SQLGetPrivateProfileString failed with .
```

All my DSN's are also not showing up when I run:

```
odbcinst -q -d
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Type the command: `env |grep 'ODBC'` to check if the `ODBCSYSINI` and the `ODBCINI` variables are set. If no results are returned - you need to add the variables to the environment variable pointing to the `directory` and the path to where the `odbc.ini` file is located as follows (in my case for RHEL 6 it is located at `/etc` - others may have it on `/usr/local/etc`):

Edit `~\.bash_profile` and add the following lines:

```
export ODBCSYSINI=/etc
export ODBCINI=/etc/odbc.ini
```

You are good to go!

Comment: Thanks - this helped. Does anyone know WHY does this happen?

Comment: This solved my error but I am getting SSL related errors on my spring hibernate app. Did you get anything like this??

Comment: after editing bash_profile and saved, you must refresh it. Type source ~/.bash_profile

Answer (score 2):

In my case (ubuntu 16.04) it was related to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unixodbc/+bug/298870), just not ~/.odbc.ini but /etc/odbc.ini. Adding a line to /etc/odbc.ini

`[empty-sys]`

fixed the problem.

Comment: This worked for Ubuntu 18.04.03, it provided output with the env | grep 'ODBC' command

Answer (score 1):

Its too late to answer on this question probably, but it is for those who still couldn't get this resolved using @kapil Vyas answer-

Adding to his answer, you will need to logout and then login again from your user for export commands (saved in .bash_profile) to work.

Answer (score 0):

When I had this problem, I edited `/usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini` to add:

```
[MySQL]
Description = ODBC for MySQL
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc8a.so
Setup = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libodbcmyS.so
FileUsage = 1
Pooling = Yes
CPTimeout = 120
```

I hope this is helpful.