# ODBC Driver Manager: Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: macos, macports, freetds, unixodbc

I am setting up Go, FreeTDS, and unixODBC on OSX. I followed the instructions on https://code.google.com/p/odbc/wiki/InstallingUnixODBCOnOSX, and when I tried to run the tests, I get:

```
[ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

The port installs both unixODBC **and** FreeTDS, so what is needed to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Linux you use odbcinst to register the data source, but you need to know where libtdsodbc.so is

On my Mac, it was put in

```
/opt/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
```

If that's not where yours was installed, do this to find its location:

```
sudo find / -name "libtdsodbc.so"
```

Then create a file called "tds.driver.template" with the following inside:

```
[FreeTDS]
Description = Open source FreeTDS Driver
Driver =/opt/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
```

Then run

```
sudo odbcinst -i -d -f tds.driver.template
```

Comment: where should the tds.driver.template be placed? What path?

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, the best way to do is to use a [DSN-less configuration](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/dsnless.htm) — when you encode full information required to connect to a server instance in the ODBC connection string.  The upside of this approach is that it requires exactly zero configuration of the client machine, other than making sure the `FreeTDS` `ODBC` driver is properly installed.

Note two caveats applicable to `FreeTDS` in this sort of setup though:

- You have to use the `Port` connection string key.  It's typically `1433` if you're connecting to a Microsoft® SQL Server™.
- FreeTDS has an insanely low default [TDS protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabular_Data_Stream) version — something like [5.0](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/freetdsconf.htm).

  To override this, you have to use the `TDS_Version` connection string key.  Either set it to `auto` or to a some sensible value:

  - Microsoft® SQL Server™ 7.0 → 7.0
  - 〃 2000 → 7.1
  - 〃 2005 → 7.2
  - 〃 2008 → 7.3
  - 〃 2012 → 7.4

  Looks like 7.2 is the largest TDS protocol version currently supported by `FreeTDS` but actually 7.2 is more than enough to work with typical data types, including `varbinary(max)`.

Comment: Thanks! I found I had to add `params["TDS_Version"] = "auto"` around line 54 in `mysql_test.go` to get the mssql tests to work.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this issue, and I think what fixed it was setting the `ODBCSYSINI` and `ODBCINI` environment variables (credit to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13920258/6284025) answer). For Mac, you need to set them to these values:

```
export ODBCSYSINI=/Library/ODBC
export ODBCINI=/Library/ODBC/odbc.ini
```