# HIVE ODBC connector settings

Tags: hadoop, odbc, hive, cloudera, unixodbc

I configured unixodbc to use the hive connector from cloudera in my Linux Mint machine,
but I keep receiving the following error when trying to connect to hive (e.g. using `isql -v hive`)

```
S1000][unixODBC][Cloudera][ODBC] (11560) Unable to locate SQLGetPrivateProfileString function.
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

I think I set the /etc/odbcinst.ini and the ~/.odbc.ini in the correct way:

```
# content of /etc/odbcinst.ini
[hive]
Description = Cloudera ODBC Driver for Apache Hive (64-bit)
Driver=/opt/cloudera/hiveodbc/lib/64/libclouderahiveodbc64.so
ODBCInstLib=libodbcinst.a(libodbcinst.so.1)
UsageCount  = 1
DriverManagerEncoding=UTF-16
ErrorMessagesPath=/opt/cloudera/hiveodbc/ErrorMessages/
LogLevel=0
SwapFilePath=/tmp
```

and my ~/.odbc.ini file contains:

```
[hive]
Description=Cloudera ODBC Driver for Apache Hive (64-bit) DSN 
Driver = hive
ErrorMessagesPath=/opt/cloudera/hiveodbc/ErrorMessages/
# Values for HOST, PORT, KrbHostFQDN, and KrbServiceName should be set here.
# They can also be specified on the connection string.
HOST= <the host>
PORT= <the port>
Schema=<the schema>
# .. etc
```

Can you help me find out what is causing the error?

Comment: this might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887328/sqlgetprivateprofilestring-failed-with

Comment: thanks sonic, but nope it didn't help :) I have set the env variables, but the error stays there

Comment: is this variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH set?

Comment: @sonic yes it is set

Answer (score 10):

What does

```
ldd /opt/cloudera/hiveodbc/lib/64/libclouderahiveodbc64.so
```

Show you?

It may be that the driver is not linked to libodbcinst.so.

You could try a

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/libodbcinst.so
```

or wherever libodbcinst.so is on your machine.

Comment: LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/libodbcinst.so Solved the problem for me

Comment: Worked for me too. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you ODBCInstLib is set properly?

I was hitting the same issue with a Vertica driver and my libodbcinst.so.1 ended up needing an absolute path: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbcinst.so.1

I determined the path by running a Find for libodbcinst.so.